# hibernate: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property in oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following structure in my code:

A user has a favourites list of TvShows, a TvShow has a list of seasons, a season has a list of episodes.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tvshows", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TvShow> favourites;
/// everything else removed for clarity
}
```

TvShow

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tvshows")
public class TvShow {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "tvShow_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tvshows", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Season> seasons;
/// everything else removed for clarity
}
```

Season

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seasons")
public class Season{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "season_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "seasons", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Episode> episodes;
/// everything else removed for clarity
}
```

The app won't start with the following error message:

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.gcimpoies.project.model.Season.seasons in com.gcimpoies.project.model.TvShow.seasons
```

Also,

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.gcimpoies.project.model.Season.seasons in com.gcimpoies.project.model.TvShow.seasons
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing the correct attribute names(arguments of mappedBy) but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you making unidirectional or bidirectional relationships?

Comment: I don't know the difference between them, but I would suppose bidirectional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name that you have to put inside `mappedBy` is the id of the class that you are referencing.

Instead of:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tvshows", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Try:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

You will have to do this for the rest of the mappings as well.

Comment: In that case, is the "id" field from the TvShows class? Or from another class? It's confusing since all 3 entities have the id field named "id". Which one of the 3 is the one above? Thanks!

Comment: I would change the name of the different ids in the java classes to differentiate them better; it is always a good practice.

For example, if you change the id in TvShow and name it tvShowId, the OneToMany relationship in User would be:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tvShowId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private List<TvShow> favourites;

When you tell the class that the field is a List of TvShow, Hibernate already knows which class to map, you only need to tell Hibernate which field of that class you will be using to map it.